# Access Javascript objects imported by url in html

Tags: scala.js, binding.scala

I am writing an embedded application where i am using Office 365 library to access outlook email context which is exposed to my application via global object **Office**

i wrote already javascript application in which i included script url in html page like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>
```

after i am accessing context in ES6 javascript function like below :

```
 Office.initialize = function (reason) {
            $(document).ready(function () { 
                 Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.ItemChanged, callbackfunction);
            });
        };
```

I want to do the same thing in scala JS.

For that included Office js library in html as above way.

After trying to access Office object like :

```
@js.native
@JSGlobal
object Office extends js.Any {
  def initialize(f: String => Unit):js.Any = js.native
}
```

when i call this Office object, it is throwing error.

```
def callback = (reason:String) => {
  println(s"reason called in callback function => $reason")
}
Office.initialize(callback)
```

How to instantiate and access office object in scala JS?

ERROR :

```
VM3981 playground-fastopt-bundle.js:4078 Uncaught TypeError: $g.Office.initialize is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (VM3981 playground-fastopt-bundle.js:4078)
    at mightThrow (VM4209 playground-fastopt-bundle.js:25770)
    at process (VM4209 playground-fastopt-bundle.js:25838)
```

Initialize is not available in Office object. we have to load the function on run time. 
Error message :

> add your initialization code on the Office.initialize function.

gist of code :
https://gist.github.com/rajeevprasanna/8d4f193bc328f2c2d48e113960fb25a6

Comment: What error is thrown, exactly? Also, you say you "want to do the same thing in Scala.js", but the Scala.js snippet supposedly *calls* `initialize`, whereas the JS snippet *defines* `initialize`. Which is the one you want to do? If you want to call it, where is it defined?

Comment: i want to call initialize function to initialize office context object to access fields available on office object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem in below approach :

as per error message **add your initialization code on the Office.initialize function**, i have to define a property to load the function.

```
@js.native
@JSGlobal
object Office extends js.Object {
  var initialize:js.Function1[String, _] = js.native
}
```

after loaded above function :

```
Office.initialize = { r:String =>
        println(s"function initialized. reason => $r")
      }
```

this approach is similar to event handling of button clicks.

Refer : https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-dom/blob/5adf7290a4b1fdf7759dfed120e4050f87d9f0a2/src/main/scala/org/scalajs/dom/raw/Html.scala#L416

Answer (score 0):

Given the error, it seems that the `Office.initialize` function has not been created yet at the time you try to call it. The `Office` object exists, but it has no field `initialize` (or it is not a function).

This probably just because the order of your `script` tags is not correct. Make sure that the script that is supposed to define `Office.initialize` is executed *before* the Scala.js code.

Comment: i movde code to top of class definitiion. but no luck. why it is unable to detect initialize function? code gist : https://gist.github.com/rajeevprasanna/8d4f193bc328f2c2d48e113960fb25a6

Comment: any help regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure

```
Office.initialize = { r:String =>
    println(s"function initialized. reason => $r")
  }
```

the code is valid or not But I wrote a small example and It works well.
Have a look at https://gist.github.com/abdheshkumar/f2ef0c73b942a8f5a48ec20559679105